# Is there a way to react to a discord message with the first letter of the message using DiscordJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I want to make a custom poll bot in my server discord and I'm using DiscordJS to develop it.

The code would be something like, extract the !poll from the message and only keep count of the others strings separated by a space.

Something like "!poll option1 option2 option3" And the bot would return a list with all 3 options and a reaction with the first letter of the option for every option available.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKYaR.png)

My problem is finding the reaction ID of the first letter, I already tried message.guild.emojis.cache and finding it, but those are only the customs one. I want the full list available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Regional Indicator Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol). These are Unicode characters intended to be used to encode national flag emoji sequences.

A quick way to convert between ASCII capital letters and regional indicators would be something like `String.fromCodePoint("R".codePointAt(0) - 65 + 0x1f1e6)`, which returns ""